# Is this similarity to the Fourier transform of the von Mangoldt function real?

Tags: number-theory, fourier-analysis

Mathematica knows that the logarithm of $n$ is:

$$\log(n) = \lim\limits_{s \rightarrow 1} \zeta(s)\left(1 - \frac{1}{n^{(s - 1)}}\right)$$

The von Mangoldt function should then be:

$$\Lambda(n)=\lim\limits_{s \rightarrow 1} \zeta(s)\sum\limits_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(s-1)}}.$$

Setting the first term of the von Mangoldt function $\Lambda(1)$ equal to the harmonic number $H_{\operatorname{scale}}$ where scale is equal to the scale of the Fourier transform matrix, one can calculate the Fourier transform of the von Mangoldt function with the Mathematica program at the link below:

http://pastebin.com/ZNNYZ4F6

In the program I studied the function within the limit for the von Mangoldt function, and made some small changes to the function itself:

$f(t)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=k} \frac{1}{\log(k)} \frac{1}{n} \zeta(1/2+i \cdot t)\sum\limits_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(1/2+i \cdot t-1)}}$
as $k$ goes to infinity.

(Edit 20.9.2013: The function $f(t)$ had "-1" in the argument for the zeta function.)

The plot of this function looks like this:

[image: function]

While the plot of the Fourier transform of the von Mangoldt function with the program looks like this:

[image: Fourier transform]

There are some similarities but the Fourier transform converges faster towards smaller oscillations in between the spikes at zeta zeros and the scale factor is wrong.

Will the function $f(t)$ above eventually converge to the Fourier transform of the von Mangoldt function, or is it only yet another meaningless plot?

Now when I look at it I think the spikes at zeros comes from the zeta function itself and the spectrum like feature comes from the Möbius function which inverts the zeta function.

In the Fourier transform the von Mangoldt function has this form:

$$\log (\text{scale}) ,\log (2),\log (3),\log (2),\log (5),0,\log (7),\log (2),\log (3),0,\log (11),0,...,\Lambda(\text{scale})$$

$$scale = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...k$$

Or as latex:

$$\Lambda(n) = \begin{cases} \log q & \text{if }n=1, \\\log p & \text{if }n=p^k \text{ for some prime } p \text{ and integer } k \ge 1, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

$$n=1,2,3,4,5,...q$$

```
TableForm[Table[Table[If[n == 1, Log[q], MangoldtLambda[n]], {n, 1, q}],
{q, 1, 12}]]
```

---

```
scale = 50; (*scale = 5000 gives the plot below*)
Print["Counting to 60"]
Monitor[g1 = 
  ListLinePlot[
   Table[Re[
     Zeta[1/2 + I*k]*
      Total[Table[
        Total[MoebiusMu[Divisors[n]]/Divisors[n]^(1/2 + I*k - 1)]/(n*
           k), {n, 1, scale}]]], {k, 0 + 1/1000, 60, N[1/6]}], 
   DataRange -> {0, 60}, PlotRange -> {-0.15, 1.5}], Floor[k]]
```

Dirichlet series:

[image: zeta zero spectrum 1]

---

```
Clear[f];
scale = 100000;
f = ConstantArray[0, scale];
f[[1]] = N@HarmonicNumber[scale];
Monitor[Do[
  f[[i]] = N@MangoldtLambda[i] + f[[i - 1]], {i, 2, scale}], i]
xres = .002;
xlist = Exp[Range[0, Log[scale], xres]];
tmax = 60;
tres = .015;
Monitor[errList = 
   Table[(xlist^(1/2 + I k - 1).(f[[Floor[xlist]]] - xlist)), {k, 
     Range[0, 60, tres]}];, k]
ListLinePlot[Im[errList]/Length[xlist], DataRange -> {0, 60}, 
 PlotRange -> {-.01, .15}]
```

Fourier transform:

[image: zeta zero spectrum 2]

---

Matrix inverse:

```
Clear[n, k, t, A, nn];
nn = 50;
A = Table[
   Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, 1/(n/k)^(1/2 + I*t - 1), 0], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1,
     nn}];
MatrixForm[A];
ListLinePlot[
 Table[Total[
   1/Table[n*t, {n, 1, nn}]*
    Total[Transpose[Re[Inverse[A]*Zeta[1/2 + I*t]]]]], {t, 1/1000, 60,
    N[1/6]}], DataRange -> {0, 60}, PlotRange -> {-0.15, 1.5}]
```

---

```
Clear[n, k, t, A, nn];
nnn = 12;
Show[Flatten[{Table[
    ListLinePlot[
     Table[Re[
       Total[1/Table[n*t, {n, 1, nn}]*
         Total[Transpose[
           Inverse[
             Table[Table[
               If[Mod[n, k] == 0, N[1/(n/k)^(1/2 + I*t - 1)], 0], {k, 
                1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}]]*Zeta[1/2 + I*t]]]]], {t, 1/1000,
        60, N[1/10]}], DataRange -> {0, 60}, 
     PlotRange -> {-0.15, 1.5}], {nn, 1, nnn}], 
   Table[ListLinePlot[
     Table[Re[
       Total[1/Table[n*t, {n, 1, nn}]*
         Total[Transpose[
           Inverse[
             Table[Table[
               If[Mod[n, k] == 0, N[1/(n/k)^(1/2 + I*t - 1)], 0], {k, 
                1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}]]*Zeta[1/2 + I*t]]]]], {t, 1/1000,
        60, N[1/10]}], DataRange -> {0, 60}, 
     PlotRange -> {-0.15, 1.5}, PlotStyle -> Red], {nn, nnn, nnn}]}]]
```

12 first curves together or partial sums:

[image: 12 curves]

```
Clear[n, k, t, A, nn, dd];
dd = 220;
Print["Counting to ", dd];
nn = 20;
A = Table[
   Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, 1/(n/k)^(1/2 + I*t - 1), 0], {k, 1, 
     nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
Monitor[g1 = 
   ListLinePlot[
    Table[Total[
      1/Table[n*t, {n, 1, nn}]*
       Total[Transpose[
         Re[Inverse[
           IdentityMatrix[nn] + (Inverse[A] - IdentityMatrix[nn])*
             Zeta[1/2 + I*t]]]]]], {t, 1/1000, dd, N[1/100]}], 
    DataRange -> {0, dd}, PlotRange -> {-7, 7}];, Floor[t]];
mm = N[2*Pi/Log[2], 20];
g2 = Graphics[
   Table[Style[Text[n, {mm*n, 1}], FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
     FontSize -> 14], {n, 1, 32}]];
Show[g1, g2, ImageSize -> Large];
```

Matrix Inverse of matrix inverse times zeta function (on critical line):

[image: matrix inverse of matrix inverse as function of t]

```
Clear[n, k, t, A, nn, h];
nn = 60;
h = 2; (*h=2 gives log 2 operator, h=3 gives log 3 operator and so on*)
A = Table[
   Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, 
     If[Mod[n/k, h] == 0, 1 - h, 1]/(n/k)^(1/2 + I*t - 1), 0], {k, 1, 
     nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
MatrixForm[A];
g1 = ListLinePlot[
   Table[Total[
     1/Table[n*t, {n, 1, nn}]*
      Total[Transpose[Re[Inverse[A]*Zeta[1/2 + I*t]]]]], {t, 1/1000, 
     nn, N[1/6]}], DataRange -> {0, nn}, PlotRange -> {-3, 7}];
mm = N[2*Pi/Log[h], 12];
g2 = Graphics[
   Table[Style[Text[n*2*Pi/Log[h], {mm*n, 1}], 
     FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 14], {n, 1, 32}]];
Show[g1, g2, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Matrix inverse of Riemann zeta times log 2 operator:

[image: 2 Pi div log2 spectrum]

[Jeffrey Stopple's code](http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~stopple/zeta.html):

```
Show[Graphics[
  RasterArray[
   Table[Hue[
     Mod[3 Pi/2 + Arg[Zeta[sigma + I t]], 2 Pi]/(2 Pi)], {t, -30, 
     30, .1}, {sigma, -30, 30, .1}]]], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Normal or usual zeta:

[image: Normal zeta]

```
Show[Graphics[
  RasterArray[
   Table[Hue[
     Mod[3 Pi/2 + 
        Arg[Sum[Zeta[sigma + I t]*
           Total[1/Divisors[n]^(sigma + I t - 1)*
              MoebiusMu[Divisors[n]]]/n, {n, 1, 30}]], 
       2 Pi]/(2 Pi)], {t, -30, 30, .1}, {sigma, -30, 30, .1}]]], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Spectral zeta (30-th partial sum):

[image: spectral zeta]

```
Clear[n, k, t, A, nn, B];
nn = 60;
A = Table[
  Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, 1/(n/k)^(1/2 + I*t - 1), 0], {k, 1, 
    nn}], {n, 1, nn}]; MatrixForm[A];
B = FourierDCT[
   Table[Total[
     1/Table[n, {n, 1, nn}]*
      Total[Transpose[Re[Inverse[A]*Zeta[1/2 + I*t]]]]], {t, 1/1000, 
     600, N[1/6]}]];
g1 = ListLinePlot[B[[1 ;; 700]]*Table[Sqrt[n], {n, 1, 700}], 
   DataRange -> {0, 60}, PlotRange -> {-60, 600}];
mm = 11.35/Log[2];
g2 = Graphics[
   Table[Style[Text[n, {mm*Log[n], 100 + 20*(-1)^n}], 
     FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 14], {n, 1, 16}]];
Show[g1, g2, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Mobius function -> Dirichlet series -> Spectral Riemann zeta -> Fourier transform -> von Mangoldt function:

[image: from Mobius via spectral Riemann zeta to von Mangoldt]

Larger von Mangoldt function plot still wrong amplitude:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/02A1p.jpg

```
Clear[n, k, t, A, nn, B, g1, g2];
nn = 32;
A = Table[
   Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, 1/(n/k)^(1/2 + I*t - 1), 0], {k, 1, 
     nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
MatrixForm[A];
B = FourierDCT[
   Table[Total[
     1/Table[n, {n, 1, nn}]*
      Total[Transpose[Re[Inverse[A]*Zeta[1/2 + I*t]]]]], {t, 0, 2000, 
     N[1/6]}]];
g1 = ListLinePlot[B[[1 ;; 2000]], DataRange -> {0, 60}, 
   PlotRange -> {-5, 50}];
2*N[Length[B]/1500, 12];
mm = 13.25/Log[2];
g2 = Graphics[
   Table[Style[Text[n, {mm*Log[n], 7 + (-1)^n}], 
     FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 14], {n, 1, 40}]];
Show[g1, g2, ImageSize -> Full]
```

Plot from program above: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6mTJ.jpg

Partial sums of zeta function, use this one:

```
Clear[n, k, t, A, nn, B];
nn = 80;
mm = 11.35/Log[2];
A = Table[
   Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, 1/(n/k)^(1/2 + I*t - 1), 0], {k, 1, 
     nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
MatrixForm[A];
B = Re[FourierDCT[
    Monitor[Table[
      Total[1/Table[
          n, {n, 1, nn}]*(Total[
           Transpose[Inverse[A]*Sum[1/j^(1/2 + I*t), {j, 1, nn}]]] - 
          1)], {t, 1/1000, 600, N[1/6]}], Floor[t]]]];
g1 = ListLinePlot[B[[1 ;; 700]], DataRange -> {0, 60/mm}, 
   PlotRange -> {-30, 30}];
g2 = Graphics[
   Table[Style[Text[n, {Log[n], 5 - (-1)^n}], 
     FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 14], {n, 1, 32}]];
Show[g1, g2, ImageSize -> Full]
```

---

Edit 17.1.2015:

```
Clear[g1, g2, scale, xres, x, a, c, d, datapointsdisplayed];
scale = 1000000;
xres = .00001;
x = Exp[Range[0, Log[scale], xres]];
a = -FourierDCT[
    Log[x]*FourierDST[
      MangoldtLambda[Floor[x]]*(SawtoothWave[x] - 1)*(x)^(-1/2)]];
c = 62.357;
d = N[Im[ZetaZero[1]]];
datapointsdisplayed = 500000;
ymin = -1.5;
ymax = 3;
p = 0.013;
g1 = ListLinePlot[a[[1 ;; datapointsdisplayed]], 
   PlotRange -> {ymin, ymax}, 
   DataRange -> {0, N[Im[ZetaZero[1]]]/c*datapointsdisplayed}];
Show[g1, Graphics[
  Table[Style[Text[n, {22800*Log[n], -1/4*(-1)^n}], 
    FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 14], {n, 1, 12}]], 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: MangoldLambdaTautology]

```
Show[Graphics[
  RasterArray[
   Table[Hue[
     Mod[3 Pi/2 + 
        Arg[Sum[Zeta[sigma - I t]*
           Total[1/Divisors[n]^(sigma + I t)*MoebiusMu[Divisors[n]]]/
            n, {n, 1, 30}]], 2 Pi]/(2 Pi)], {t, -30, 
     30, .1}, {sigma, -30, 30, .1}]]], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: spectral riemann]

The following is a relationship:

Let $\mu(n)$ be the Möbius function, then:

$$a(n) = \sum\limits_{d|n} d \cdot \mu(d)$$

$$T(n,k)=a(GCD(n,k))$$

$$T = \left(   \begin{array}{ccccccc}   +1&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1&\cdots \\ +1&-1&+1&-1&+1&-1&+1 \\ +1&+1&-2&+1&+1&-2&+1 \\ +1&-1&+1&-1&+1&-1&+1 \\ +1&+1&+1&+1&-4&+1&+1 \\ +1&-1&-2&-1&+1&+2&+1 \\ +1&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1&-6 \\ \vdots&&&&&&&\ddots \end{array}   \right)$$

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{T(n,k)}{n^c \cdot k^z} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\lim\limits_{s \rightarrow z} \zeta(s)\sum\limits_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(s-1)}}}{n^c} = \frac{\zeta(z) \cdot \zeta(c)}{\zeta(c + z - 1)}$$

which is part of the limit:

$$\frac{\zeta '(s)}{\zeta (s)}=\lim_{c\to 1} \, \left(\zeta (c)-\frac{\zeta (c) \zeta (s)}{\zeta (c+s-1)}\right)$$

Comment: some code: http://pastebin.com/sT3zbSTP  and a picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5LirM.jpg

Comment: It seems this would work well on MO to me as well. We (lowly site mods) cannot migrate questions that are more than 30 days old, so I've asked a SE mod to migrate it for you.

Comment: Actually, this is simply too old to be migrated at all. I encourage you to simply ask it again on MO with a reference back here so that they know it was asked here first.

Comment: I have now posted at Math Overflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/162076/is-this-riemann-zeta-function-product-equal-to-the-fourier-transform-of-the-von

Comment: I cant say I know the field, but the Mathematica StackExchange site sometimes handles [stuff like this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37007/von-mangoldt-function).  Btw- they like their questions brief and to the point !

Comment: so this was answered on overflow?

Answer (score 4):

The Laplace transform of a function

$\sum _{i=1}^{\infty } a_i \delta (t-\log (i))$ 
where $\delta (t-\log (i))$ is the Delta function (i.e Unit impulse) at time $\log(i)$

is

$\int_0^{\infty } e^{-s t} \sum _{i=1}^{\infty } a_i \delta (t-\log (i)) \,
   dt$

or

$\sum _{i=1}^{\infty } a_i i^{-s}$

Your $a_i$ are $log(p)$ if $i = prime^k$ else 0, so it is the Laplace transform (of what you think) which is very closely related to Fourier transform.  You might find that $\sum _{i=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{s} a_i i^{-s} $ gives smoother results (although it then becomes a sum of $a_i$)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer but I want show that there is nothing mysterious going on here.

We want to prove that:

$$\text{Fourier Transform of } \Lambda(1)...\Lambda(k) \sim \sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=\infty} \frac{1}{n} \zeta(s)\sum\limits_{d|n}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(s-1)}}$$

The Dirichlet inverse of the Euler totient function is

$$a(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n} \mu(d)d$$

Construct the matrix $$T(n,k)=a(GCD(n,k))$$

which starts:

$$\displaystyle T = \begin{bmatrix} +1&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1&\cdots \\ +1&-1&+1&-1&+1&-1&+1 \\ +1&+1&-2&+1&+1&-2&+1 \\ +1&-1&+1&-1&+1&-1&+1 \\ +1&+1&+1&+1&-4&+1&+1 \\ +1&-1&-2&-1&+1&+2&+1 \\ +1&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1&-6 \\ \vdots&&&&&&&\ddots \end{bmatrix}
$$

where GCD is the Greatest Common Divisor of row index $n$ and column index $k$.

joriki [showed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/51708/8530) that the von Mangoldt function is $$\Lambda(n)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{k=\infty} \frac{T(n,k)}{k}$$

Then add this quote by Terence Tao from [here](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/harmonicanalysis/conversations/messages/230), that I don't completely understand but I do almost see why it should be true:

Quote:" The Fourier transform in this context becomes (essentially) the Mellin transform, which is particularly important in analytic number theory. (For instance, the Riemann zeta function is essentially the Mellin transform of the Dirac comb on the natural numbers"

Now let us return to the matrix $T$:

First the von Mangoldt is expanded as:

$$\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix} +1/1&+1/1&+1/1&+1/1&+1/1&+1/1&+1/1&\cdots \\ +1/2&-1/2&+1/2&-1/2&+1/2&-1/2&+1/2 \\ +1/3&+1/3&-2/3&+1/3&+1/3&-2/3&+1/3 \\ +1/4&-1/4&+1/4&-1/4&+1/4&-1/4&+1/4 \\ +1/5&+1/5&+1/5&+1/5&-4/5&+1/5&+1/5 \\ +1/6&-1/6&-2/6&-1/6&+1/6&+2/6&+1/6 \\ +1/7&+1/7&+1/7&+1/7&+1/7&+1/7&-6/7 \\ \vdots&&&&&&&\ddots \end{bmatrix}$$

**Edit: 24.1.2016.** From here on the variables $n$ and $k$ should be permutated but I don't know how to fix the rest of this answer right now.

Summing the columns first is equivalent to what was said earlier:
$$\Lambda(n)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{k=\infty} \frac{T(n,k)}{k}$$

where:

$$\Lambda(n) = \begin{cases} \infty & \text{if }n=1, \\\log p & \text{if }n=p^k \text{ for some prime } p \text{ and integer } k \ge 1, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

or as a sequence:

$$\infty ,\log (2),\log (3),\log (2),\log (5),0,\log (7),\log (2),\log (3),0,\log (11),0,...,\Lambda(\infty)$$

And now based on the quote above let us say that:
$$\text{Fourier Transform of } \Lambda(1)...\Lambda(k) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=k}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}$$

Expanding this into matrix form we have the matrix:

$$\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{T(1,1)}{1 \cdot 1^s}&+\frac{T(1,2)}{1 \cdot 2^s}&+\frac{T(1,3)}{1 \cdot 3^s}+&\cdots&+\frac{T(1,k)}{1 \cdot k^s} \\
\frac{T(2,1)}{2 \cdot 1^s}&+\frac{T(2,2)}{2 \cdot 2^s}&+\frac{T(2,3)}{2 \cdot 3^s}+&\cdots&+\frac{T(2,k)}{2 \cdot k^s} \\
\frac{T(3,1)}{3 \cdot 1^s}&+\frac{T(3,2)}{3 \cdot 2^s}&+\frac{T(3,3)}{3 \cdot 3^s}+&\cdots&+\frac{T(3,k)}{3 \cdot k^s} \\
 \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\
\frac{T(n,1)}{n \cdot 1^s}&+\frac{T(n,2)}{n \cdot 2^s}&+\frac{T(n,3)}{n \cdot 3^s}+&\cdots&+\frac{T(n,k)}{n \cdot k^s} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\zeta(s)}{1} \\ +\frac{\zeta(s)\sum\limits_{d|2} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(s-1)}}}{2} \\ +\frac{\zeta(s)\sum\limits_{d|3} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(s-1)}}}{3} \\ \vdots \\ +\frac{\zeta(s)\sum\limits_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(s-1)}}}{n} \end{bmatrix}$$

On the right hand side we see that it sums to the right hand side of what we set out to prove, namely:

$$\text{Fourier Transform of } \Lambda(1)...\Lambda(k) \sim \sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=\infty} \frac{1}{n} \zeta(s)\sum\limits_{d|n}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(s-1)}}$$

Things that remain unclear are: What factor should the left hand side be multiplied with in order to have the same magnitude as the right hand side? And why in the Fourier transform does the first term of the von Mangoldt function appear to be $\log q$?

$$\Lambda(n) = \begin{cases} \log q & \text{if }n=1, \\\log p & \text{if }n=p^k \text{ for some prime } p \text{ and integer } k \ge 1, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

$$n=1,2,3,4,5,...q$$

As a heuristic, $$\Lambda(n) = \log q \;\;\;\; \text{if }n=1$$ probably has to do with that in the Fourier transform $q$ terms of $\Lambda$ are used and the first column in square matrix $T(1..q,1..q)$ sums to a Harmonic number.